# Can Craft convert requested url to lowercase?

Tags: url

I think this is normally done with .htaccess or httpd.conf, but it's a bit cumbersome on shared hosting, and it seems like a simple trick for a CMS...

Can Craft convert requested URLs to lowercase? So if the slug for the page is /meditate, but someone types in /Meditate that Craft delivers /meditate page?

I don't quite understand how one uses customAsciiCharMappings -- it seems unrelated to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your server is configured, this may be a non-issue. I just checked several sites, and they all work fine with mixed-case URLs.

If that's not the case with your site, you'll need to implement a simple plugin, which checks the URL, converts it to lowercase, and redirects the visitor (if required).

Hopefully it goes without saying that it would be *much* better to do this in your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`.

Caveats dispensed with, here's an example plugin.

```
<?php namespace Craft;

class PoorMansRedirectPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    // Standard plugin methods omitted for brevity.


    /**
     * Runs before *every* request.
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $path = craft()->request->getPath();
        $lowerPath = strtolower($path);

        // If the current path is not lowercased, redirect.
        if ($path !== $lowerPath) {
            $url = UrlHelper::getUrl($lowerPath);
            craft()->request->redirect($url);
        }
    }
}
```

Just to be clear, this is a really bare-bones solution.

It doesn't make any distinction between site URLs and admin URLs, doesn't account for query strings, will break POST requests, and a lot more besides.

As such it is in no way production ready, and would require quite a bit of additional work to account for all of these edge (and not so edge) cases. See my previous note regarding `.htaccess` being vastly preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. On our server, the case needs to be exact. I never thought about messing up POSTs, and it turns out the .htaccess fix for it, though long, isn't noticibly slow. So .htaccess it is!

Answer (score 1):

This is the .htaccess which is working for me now. From this [site](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/)

**Htaccess to Redirect Uppercase to Lowercase**

This should go at the very top of your .htaccess file. At least it should go above ANY other RewriteRules. That is because this uses a loop, until there are no more uppercase characters to convert, it will keep starting at the first HASCAPS:TRUE RewriteRule. Oh, and this is actually really quick and isn't gonna slow down anything.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```